# Struct in one Xcode file not working/being recognized in another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, struct

I have created a struct 'QuizBrain' in a new file labeled QuizBrain.swift, with intention to utilize in in my ViewController.swift file.  However, when I go to the view controller file and set the struct equal to a variable 'var quizBrain = Quizbrain()' , the struct stays white and doesn't highlight to any color, and all of its elements are unaccessible in the view controller file.  I don't know why the view controller file won't recognize it as a struct.  Here's the *unfinished* QuizBrain.swift code :

```
    import Foundation

struct QuizBrain {
    let quiz = [
        Question(q: "A slug's blood is green.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "The total surface area of two human lungs is approximately 70 square metres.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are technically entitled to a state funeral, because the building is considered too sacred a place.", a: "False"),
        Question(q: "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", a: "False"),
        Question(q: "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", a: "True"),
        Question(q: "The loudest sound produced by any animal is 188 decibels. That animal is the African Elephant.", a: "False"),
        Question(q: "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", a: "False"),
        Question(q: "Chocolate affects a dog's heart and nervous system; a few ounces are enough to kill a small dog.", a: "True")
    ]

     var questionNumber = 0

    func checkAnswer(_ userAnswer: String) {
        if userAnswer == quiz[questionNumber].answer {
            // User got it right
        } else {
            // User got it wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the *unfinished* view controller code with a function attempting to utilize the structure's elements :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!


var quizBrain = QuizBrain() 



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    updateUI()

}

@IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle! // True or false
    quizBrain.checkAnswer(userAnswer)


    if userAnswer == actualAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    if (questionNumber + 1 ) < quiz.count {
        questionNumber += 1
    } else {
        questionNumber = 0
    }

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


}
```

Parts of the struct like checkAnswer and questionNumber are giving me errors of unresolved identifiers... so I assume the struct is not going across the files for some reason.

Also this code is an exercise in a Udemy course, I believe I have the same code as the teacher but obviously this is a problem for me, maybe Apple changed how this works?

Comment: As you are a beginner go ahead and print `quizBrain` first. Add a break point and see its value.

Comment: print it where and how? the code is incomplete so i cannot build the app.

Comment: I solved the problem!  I had to make sure that each file was under the correct target membership in the file inspector.  Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a struct defined in one file is not working/autocompleting in another file, go to the file inspector for each, and make sure they are under the correct 'target membership'.  If the box is checked for each of the files under the same target membership, you should be good to go.  If it's still not working, try unchecking and rechecking each box and pressing command B.  Worst case scenario, copy and paste all the code and remake each file (except view controller), then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Press CMD + B or click Analyze menu option to check code. It should start recognizing the file. In case this does not work for you. You can check Target Membership field,

1. Select the file and click on "Show the File Inspector" icon
2. Check the Target Membership field and compare it with ViewController target membership.
3. Set the Struct file membership to the same as ViewController membership
4. Wait for few seconds and now check ViewController code. It should access